# Please share a sample code of thread_local in c++

Tags: c++, thread-local

Do the variables declared with thread_local need to be allocate by '[LocalAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc)'?

If I have a class defined as:

```
class B2 
{
public: 
  int data;
};thread_local B2 BObject2;
```

How do use this class in the sample code of this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-thread-local-storage-in-a-dynamic-link-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: You're confusing a C++ language feature and a Windows OS API.  `thread_local` and `LocalAlloc` have nothing at all to do with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing two different things here.

[thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) is defined by the C++ 11 standard, so it's up to the c++ runtime to figure out how to implement it.  thread_local is platform agnostic.  So no you don't need to use "LocalAlloc".

The article you pointed to pre-dates the C++ 11 standard and is the raw services supplied by Win32 (windows) to create thread local data.

I would not mix the usage of the two types.  It's most likely that the MSVC C++ standard library will implement thread_local using those win32 services.

Since thread_local is platform agnostic I would recommend that you use that and it will make your code cross-platform (in that regard) and it leaves it up to the MSVC C++ runtime to get it right.

Comment: Thanks Shane. How do I use the ' BObject2;' ? do you have sample code?

Comment: Like any other object instance.  There is no difference except that the instance data is local to the thread.  So each thread has it's own instance data.

Comment: Hi Shane, you are saying that 'So no you don't need to use "LocalAlloc"... what does this mean? If I use thread_local to decorate a class, it will be treated as a thread local storage variable?  If yes, how do I retrieve the value from slot? I don't even have a Index defined yet.

Comment: Your getting very confused... Ignore everything to do with that win32 link.  You don't need to know ANYTHING about it.  All you need to understand is the thread_local link only.  If you read thread_local link correctly. All you need to do is declare a static / global variable with thread_local and your done.  Use the variable as you would. e.g. static thread_local int x;  Where static int x will have the same value across ALL threads.  static thread_local int x will have a DIFFERENT value per thread in your process.

Comment: At the bottom of the link is a example that uses thread_local as well.